# llvmpipe on fresh install

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, intel

I have just tried to fix a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Tuxedo InfinityBook v3 13 UHD i7 8550u with integrated graphics card for a few hours to no avail.

`lshw -c display` shows

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    ...
```

And the settings tab shows that the rendering mode is `llvmpipe`.

Further, I have to set `nomodeset` in grub to make the system boot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me helped setting `i915.alpha_support=1`. Try using instuction below:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (you may use whatever editor instead of `nano`)
2. Add `i915.alpha_support=1` to the existing line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` after `quiet splash`.
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

P.S. My backgound with this problem:

Initially I had a blackscreen after splash, so I had to add `nomodeset` (afterwards replaced to `i915.modeset=0`). Doing this I could boot the desktop, but it was rendered by LLVMpipe (software rendering using CPU capabilities).